# OpenTok UI elemnts are not positioned in my HTML DOM elements

Tags: javascript, html, opentok

I using OpenTok to add video broadcusting for my app. 
The app is using a menu on the left side, and tabs on the right side.
I added 2 DIV elements to the right side:

```html
<div id="myPublisherDiv1"></div>
<div id="myPublisherDiv2"></div>
```

```html
//Replace the first parameter with the replacement element ID:
 var publisher = OT.initPublisher("myPublisher1",
                                  {width:400, height:300});
 
//Replace with your API key and replacement element ID:
 var subscriber = session.subscribe(tokObj['apiKey'],
                                    "myPublisher2",
                                    {width:400, height:300})
 session.publish(publisher);
```

But the UI is displayed on top of the menu in the left side.

Answer (score 0):

Did you typo `OT.initPublisher("myPublisher1"` instead of `OT.initPublisher("myPublisherDiv1"` ? Same with the `subscribe` block.

Answer (score 0):

Use this :-

```
var session = OT.initSession(apiKey, sessionId); 
session.on({ 
streamCreated: function(event) { 
session.subscribe(event.stream, 'myPublisherDiv1', {width: 1115, height: 626}); 
} 
}); 
session.connect(token, function(error) {
if (error) {
     } else {
         session.publish('myPublisherDiv2', {width: 232, height: 174}); 
     }
});
```